# Is it possible to add custom global Symfony2 route variables like _format and _locale?

Tags: symfony, sonata, symfony-2.7

In my Symfony2 project, I have a news site which has posts. Those posts can be published in different regions. The current region (user choice) has to be part of the url. So the URLs should look like this:

```
/mag => main news site, no region selection
/mag/region1/ => posts for region 1
/mag/region2/ => ...
/mag/region1/my-news-post-slug => detail view of one post
```

For the news posts, I used the [Sonata News Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/news/master/doc/index.html).

Now my question is, **how do I add the region choice of the user to the route system without having to change each controller and template of the bundles I use?**
When I just add it to the routing config like

```
magazin:
    resource:   '@SonataNewsBundle/Resources/config/routing/news.xml'
    prefix:     /mag/{region}
```

I get a errors because this parameter is not set when generating the route in the controllers and templates of the news bundle (and others). I need something like the `{_format}` or `{_locale}` route variables which are already added by routing component obviously. Is it possible to add "global" values like that?

Comment: I suppose you could use an event listener to strip out the region number and add it as a _region attribute.  I don't understand how you would make use of this attribute without down stream changes.

Comment: I extended the news bundle with the easy extends bundle and adjusted 2 methods in the controller. I don't want to copy and edit all of the code of the original bundles but just the few things I really need to change/extend.

Comment: Yep.  That's always one of the dangers of using 3rd party bundles.  Maybe a trait could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at how Symfony does this with locale.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/LocaleListener.php

They use an event listener to capture the locale from the request parameters and add it to the router's context parameters.

Comment: This works like a charm. Although the `Request` object does not have a dedicated property, but having it just inside the parameter bag is fine for me. At first it did not work, but I just forgot to register the listener as a service. This is done in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2aeaa22e3171b5e1f10f2cc2a7ff7f6608b65f9d/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/web.xml for the locale example.